# Solution of QM tasks by using asymptotics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations, approximations, asymptotics

When we solve QM tasks by solving the Schrödinger equation, such as tasks about a particle in a Morse potential, a Poschl-Teller potential and many others, we usually find approximations (lets call them as $f_{i}(x_{j})$) of the wave-function $\Psi (x_{j})$ in equilibrium points $x_{i}$. Then we substitute $\Psi (x_{j}) = \psi(x_{j})\prod_{i}f_{i}(x_{i})$ into the Schrödinger equation and then in most cases magically obtain a hypergeometric equation for $\psi (x_{j})$ (or something like this equation; if not, we can reduce the equation to a hypergeometric one by simple substitution).

I don't understand why it works. Sometimes it seems similar to finding the solution in a form of a generalized series, but in the other cases I can't come up with a corresponding interpretation. I don't like an interpretation which refers to an idea that $\psi (x_{j})$ crosslinks asymptotics, because it is too abstract and doesn't explain why the method works in most cases (as for me). So what is the explanation?

Maybe it is connected with a strict method of bringing the equation to hypergeometric type? But how exactly?

Answer (score 3):

The Schrödinger equation is but a differential equation, so, then, solvable by one of the most effective iterative approximation techniques for such, namely [WP:Asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis); 
[WP:Asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion);
[WP:Asymptotic theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_theory); etc...

Asymptotic analysis consists of either starting from a base solution and improving it iteratively as a series, or else, more suitably, by inferring the *asymptotic dominant balance*, as outlined and illustrated in the first article. I'm not sure what type of physical interpretation you are seeking in a mere differential equation.

To appreciate the strict definition of asymptotics, consider the WP:[Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).